# how to overwrite the $http object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest

I'm using &http in angular js to make REST calls. And when I make a new call, I want to dismiss the previous call. So I wrap the data call in the service and call the service in the controller. And I'm using the global parameter to save the last call object. So whenever I call the function getsth(), it will replace the lastcall with the new one. But when I debug, it did replace the lastcall with new one, but the previous then still triggers. One solution is the cancel the previous call and I tried it works. But my question is can I overwrite the $http object so that I don't have to handle it. Thanks

Controller:

```
var lastCall;
$scope.getsth = function(){
    lastcall = service.datacall();
    lastcall.then()
}
```

Service:

```
service.datacall = function(){
    var promises = [];
    promises.push($http({url:method...}).then(function))
    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: You can add a decorator, or interceptor... overwriting the object entirely would be an extremely terrible idea.

Comment: @DanPantry Thant's true. I decided to use the cancel feature for the $http. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blogpost explains your use-case pretty well:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx

```
app.factory("movies", function($http, $q){
    var getById = function(id){
        var canceller = $q.defer();

        var cancel = function(reason){
            canceller.resolve(reason);
        };

        var promise =
            $http.get("/api/movies/slow/" + id, { timeout: canceller.promise})
                .then(function(response){
                   return response.data;
                });

        return {
            promise: promise,
            cancel: cancel
        };
    };

    return {
        getById: getById
    };
});

app.controller("mainController", function($scope, movies) {

    $scope.movies = [];
    $scope.requests = [];
    $scope.id = 1;

    $scope.start = function(){

        var request = movies.getById($scope.id++);
        $scope.requests.push(request);
        request.promise.then(function(movie){
            $scope.movies.push(movie);
            clearRequest(request);
        }, function(reason){
            console.log(reason);
        });
    };

    $scope.cancel = function(request){
        request.cancel("User cancelled");
        clearRequest(request);
    };

    var clearRequest = function(request){
        $scope.requests.splice($scope.requests.indexOf(request), 1);
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes, I implemented the cancel function in my service and it works. And I'm just wondering there's a better way to do it

Comment: overriding the $http object would be a very painful thing IMO, so no I don't think there is a 'better' way. Sorry.